# Not able to use controller in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't access rails objects created in my controller in my view. This should print "test" in the view, but does not:

test_index.html.erb:

```
<%= label_tag(@test) %>
```

test_controller.rb:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @test = "test"
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'test/test_index'
  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

Comment: It looks like a routing problem - try putting a `fail` in the index action in the controller to ensure that that action is being called.

Comment: What does it do? And why are you expecting the `index` controller to use `test_index.html.erb` as the view?

Comment: @ronan_mac putting fail "failed" in the index action does nothing

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks I figured it out. Should have been using `test_index`, instead of just `index` in the controller..

Answer (score 2):

In your route file I believe you are missing the `to:` statement

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'test/test_index', to: 'test#index'
  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```